# Not all TV shows available to redownload on iTunes show up on Apple TV

Tags: itunes, appletv, itunes-store

Some TV Shows that are available to re-download on iTunes is not showing up on my Apple TV. Now I understand that not every show I purchased is available for re-download (2, exactly) - but those that are available on iTunes should theoretically be available on the Apple TV as well, right? Here are some screenshots to show what I mean:

Apple TV:
[image]
iTunes:
[image]

I tried resetting my Apple TV a couple of times because I read online this might help, but it's not helping me. It still only shows 12 available items on my Apple TV whilst iTunes on my Mac shows 15.

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to ask Apple about the specifics of your query? It seems more like a [customer support question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128579/165931) that is narrowly focused on your account and not something we can guess what is actually happening. Is there some FAQ where Apple says that all shows are equally available on iTunes and Apple TV? My experience is things are not equally available as a rule.

Answer (score 2):

They are all available, it's just a numbering and naming inconsistency between the devices.

On the Apple TV, the "All TV Shows 12" is referring to the total number of *distinct* TV shows (example: Seinfeld, 30 Rock, The Office, etc).

In the iTunes Store > Purchased section on your Mac, the "Total: 15 items" is referring to the total number of *seasons* of all the combined different TV shows.

You have 3 seasons of "Peanuts Specials" (which iTunes treats as one distinct show) and 2 seasons of "Peanuts' Charlie Brown" (another distinct show). So the total number of distinct TV shows is 12.

Comment: -1 Looking at that screenshot of iTunes, this is clearly incorrect: iTunes shows fifteen *distinct shows*, with many more than fifteen episodes.

Comment: My mistake on the total episodes. On my computer, I was looking at the episodes tab in iTunes rather than seasons.

Comment: Ah, good correction. Between the three seasons of "Peanuts Specials" and two seasons of "Peanuts' Charlie Brown", there's the discrepancy. Reversed my downvote.